# How to install plugin Android Drawable Importer

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

With Android Studio 3.2, after installing plugin Android Drawable Importer no plugin after restart. There is not any error message. Install steps:

1. File => Settings => Plugins
2. Search and install Android Drawable Importer plugin.
3. Restart Android Studio.
4. No plugin installed and no errors.

Comment: I use this site for both IOS and Android icons https://appicon.co/#app-icon Try it

Comment: Update the Android studio and try it again.

Comment: I can't use this site because I need icon in xml way for android. This plugin is doing import easier.
@PronoyMukherjee already latest version of android studio.

Comment: I faced this issue but on second try it worked fine.

Comment: I have even restarted computer few times without help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved with next Android Studio update.

Answer (score 0):

Found this repo Android Studio 3.5 importer drawable plugin by Vincent Loi on github. You can download from here https://mega.nz/file/Ug03DBbQ#g6pIzlG7vCo2O7sdqIaOgSuX-yrqrOQKjbU0T3lsZ8E

Found this repo Android Studio 3.6 importer drawable plugin by Marc Prengemann from Jetbrains. You can download from here https://gpskaihu.nz/ADI-hack/

To install,

Open Android Studio (3.6 RC1 and 3.5 respectively)
close all projects
click on configure at the lower right corner of the window
click on plugin
click on install from UDisk in dropdown from top right
navigate to where downloaded zip file is located
select and restart android studio

I hope this two import plugins helps save your projects. Thanks to everyone and lets keep our creativity lightUP

Answer (score 0):

I have Android Studio Version 4.2.2,
Generally Android Drawable Importer is not shown in plugins. To install that plugin follow below steps:

1. Download zip file from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer.
2. Open Android Studio and close all projects.
3. Now Click on **Configure** lower right corner of window, and go to **Plugins**.
4. Click on [image]  icon.

5. In that select **Install Plugin from Disk...**. Now select zip file which you have downloaded.
6. At last, Restart Android Studio.